Removing a character in front of text, which seems to be locked to the text
I have exported to excel from a CRM called ACT, but all the data has a hidden question mark ie ?, at the front of each piece of data which cannot be seen in Excel. I cannot CLEAN/TRIM nor FIND & REPLACE. In fact using FIND & REPLACE Deletes the entire content of the cell if I set it to replace that ?.
I am able to see the ? when opening the exported file in Wordpad, and I can delete the ? and then use the data as I want. But I do not want to do the extra work outside of Excel because I want to automate a process, which requires that hidden ? to be removed. The ? locks in the format as text and I want that cell (and the whole DATE column) to be in Date format.
This is one such cell data from the ACT extraction to Excel: ﻿3/12/2024.
This is that same cell data having first saved it to csv and opened in Excel: ?3/12/2024. I can delete the ?, but It remains as text and the format cannot be changed. I can't even use the DATE nor DATEVALUE functions on it.
This is the same cell data from Word Pad: "?3/12/2024 and strangely, the " that should come immediately at the end of that text is shown on the next line in Word Pad, as if it belongs to the next piece of data.
All I need is to change that date from weird text to date format.
Would appreciate any help,
Rob

I googled "export ACT weird character" and this video describing your exact problem and its solution was the first result
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmijeV88YNA&pp=ygUqYWN0IGNybSB2MjQgdXBkYXRlIDggZXhwb3J0IHRvIGV4Y2VsIGlzc3Vl

Thanks Alex. Strangely, I had already seen that youtube clip, but had forgotten about using the export Wizard instead of just exporting, which I'll now try. The video clip is not quite correct because that question mark is also attached to the date field - which happens to be the only problem that I'm having.

Let us know how that goes and, if it doesn't work, the exact problem you're having. Other suggestions included trying to find export settings in ACT and making sure you're exporting to csv

Alex, Unfortunately that method does not solve my problem as using the wizard does not seem to give me access to a particular list's fields, namely the Task List and in particular the Date. I have instead, created an Excel workbook where I've written some code to work around this problem, so I'm happy to stay with that. I've wasted too many hours on this nonsense that ACT has implemented that should have been such a quick format change.  Thanks for your help though.

What a pain. Glad you figured it out
